# Was attempting a question in Spoj and the code I had written was accepted but showed memory used as 4468mb.What caused such high mem usage?

Tags: java

I just got into competitive programming and started attempting a few problems when I ran into this issue. Can anyone help me with this? Also, other people too seem to have gotten this result albeit for different questions. My question was to read input until the number 42 was encountered and print all the numbers before 42.

```
import java.util.*;

class X {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    String s = "", s1;

    while (n != 42) {
        Integer obj = Integer.valueOf(n);
        s1 = obj.toString();
        s = s + "\n" + s1;
        n = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the power of `Autoboxing`. No need to write `Integer obj = Integer.valueOf(n);`, instead use just `Integer obj = n;`.

Comment: Ok.Thanks @catscoolzhyk . But is that small piece of code the reason why I got such high memory usage?

Comment: no. Your code's complexity seem's to be `O(N)` where `N` is the number of inputs. Maybe, it was because of SPOJ overloading.

Comment: I see. Thanks @catscoolzhyk.